# Laravel Many to many relationship get specific data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
$finds = FindsUser::with('find')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

[image]

How I can get only status and find name

Comment: try select ```FindsUser::select(['id','status'])->with('find')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();```

Comment: Nope. I got status but not find's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
finds = DB::table('findsUsers')
    ->select('findsUsers.id','findsUsers.status','finds.name')
    ->join('finds','finds.id','=','findsUsers.id')
    ->where('user_id' => $user_id)
    ->get();
```

Or you can do this;

```
finds = FindsUser::select(['id','status'])->with('find:id,name')->get();
```

And another way;

```
finds = FindsUser::with(array('find'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','name');
}))->get();
```

Also this way;

```
//FindsUser model class
public function find()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Find')->select(array('id', 'name'));
}
```

Comment: This works thank you but how i can do it with eloquent

Comment: This FindsUser::select(['id','status'])->with('find:name')->get(); doesn't works

Comment: @JohnSmith i fixed now, can you try again

Comment: Nope. It returns   "id": 1,
            "status": 0,
            "find": null

Comment: Care for the id field and foreign keys. Be sure adding foreign key